# How can I get page to reload when I Use Angular UI router

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular and am trying to build a small application, I am using .Net for my web api and have coded a HttpResponseMessage Post method that returns a JWT. Before I start to use the JWT I just want to hit the back end, get the JWT and if it comes back redirect to another view. I am using UI Router to do this

My code looks something like this:

controller
    (function () {

```
function LogInController($scope, $http, $state) {

    $scope.signOn = function () {

        $http.post('http://localhost:route to my backend').then(function (response) {
            if (response.data.token) {
                $state.go("main");

            } else {
                alert('you do not have a token');
            }

        });
    };
};

app.controller("LogInController", LogInController);
```

}());

Html:
    
    Sign in

app.js

```
"use strict";
//defines the main module
var app = angular.module("app", ["ui.router"]);

app.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state("main", {
            url: "/main",
            templateUrl: "MedOrders.html",
            controller: "MedOrdersCtrl",
        });
});
```

this currently works, it hits my back end and shows me my token. I tried to change it to the following and got a ton of injector errors

app.js using UI router

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["$state"]);

app.config(function($state) {
    $stateProvider
        .state("main", {
            url: "/main",
            templateUrl: "where/my/view/lives.html",
            controller: "newViewsController"
        });
});
```

I am trying to start off simple which is why I do not have a login service and that may be my problem, but I am not quite sure, when I try to run this UI router fails silently. I end up still on the log on page but with the #/main appended. Should I be doing something to force this redirect the angualr way? And is there a way to get error messages from UI router?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the ngRoute module as dependency while you are using ui.router in the rest of the code.

Changing the dependency to ui.router will solve the errors at least

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ui.router"]);
```

Comment: thanks, I did not notice that artifact, still getting app is undefined though.

Comment: not throwing any more errors by redefining my module at the top of the log in controller, but I cant help thinking that this is not the Angular way of doing things.